# How to fix "XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

Tags: php, xml, sitemap, google-custom-search

I am trying to generate a sitemap but somehow an extra DIV tag at the initial line of xml. I need to remove this wrong tag DIV from the xml output.

I've tried to gather the logic at first and segregate the generation of the xml side at the bottom.
set header 'text/xml'.
I tried to strip_tags the whole xml string before output, but then, it shows document empty

```
private function removeImageAndEmbeds ( $content )
{
    // remove img tags
    $re1='(<img).*?\\/.*?\\/.*?\\/.*?\\/.*?\\/.*?\\/.*?(\\/>)';
    if ( $c=preg_replace("/".$re1."/is", "", $content) ) $content = $c;

    // remove embedded tags
    $re2='(<div).*?(data-oembed-url=)(".*?").*?<\\/div>.*?(<\\/div>)';
    if ( $c=preg_replace("/".$re2."/is", "", $content) ) $content = $c;

    return $content;
}

public function sitemaps ($tenantName="") {

    if ( !empty($tenantName) ) {

            $this->db->like( 't.name', str_replace('-', ' ', rawurldecode($tenantName)), 'none' );
            $results = $this->db->get($this->TBL . ' t')->result_array();

            foreach ( $results as $result ) {

                $tenantId = $result['id'];
                $tenantNameinURL = formatTenantNameinURL( $result['name'] );

                $AllItems =  $this->db->get_where($this->DIVIEW . ' di', 'di.account_id = '. $tenantId)->result_array();

                $topics = [];
                $itemIds = [];
                $ddIds = [];
                $urls = [];
                foreach ( $AllItems as $k => $item ) {
                    $pieces = explode('_', $item['id']);
                    if ( $pieces[1] === $this->ITEMTBL ) {
                        if( !in_array($item['record_id'], $itemIds) ){

                            $itemIds[] = $item['record_id'];
                            $content = $this->removeImageAndEmbeds( $item['content'] );

                            $AllItems[$k]['content'] = $content;
                            $topics[$k][] = $AllItems[$k];
                            $urls[$k]['url'] = formatFrontEndURL( $this->current_class_name, $tenantName, 'show', $pieces[0] );
                        }
                    } else if ( $pieces[1] === 'dataDefinitions' ) {
                        if( !in_array($item['record_id'], $ddIds) ){

                            $ddIds[] = $item['record_id'];
                            $content = $this->removeImageAndEmbeds( $item['content'] );

                            $AllItems[$k]['content'] = $content;
                            $topics[$k][] = $AllItems[$k];
                            $urls[$k]['url'] = formatFrontEndURL( $this->current_class_name, $tenantName, 'data_definition', $pieces[0] );
                        }
                    }
                }

                $urlset = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset />');
                $urlset->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
                foreach ($topics as $i => $itemsInTopic) {

                    $url = $urlset->addChild('url');
                    $url->loc = $urls[$i]['url'];

                    $pageMap = $url->addChild('PageMap');
                    $pageMap->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-pagemap/1.0');
                    foreach ( $itemsInTopic as $item ) {

                        $content = $item['content'];
                        $content = trim( str_replace(["&nbsp;","\r","\n","\t", "&#13;", "&#10;"], ' ', strip_tags( utf8_decode( $content ) )) );
                        $dataObject = $pageMap->addChild('DataObject');
                        $dataObject->addAttribute('type', 'document');
                        $dataObject->addAttribute('id', $item['record_id']);
                        $dataObject->Attribute[0]['name'] = 'title';
                        $dataObject->Attribute[0] = $item['title'];
                        $dataObject->Attribute[1]['name'] = 'content';
                        $dataObject->Attribute[1] = $content;
                    }
                }

                $xmlContent = $urlset->asXML();
                $this->output->set_content_type('text/xml')->set_output( $xmlContent );
            }
        }
  }
```

here are two errors generated from seochat validator
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vacmuJL6hnMErzqZ5zZWkkObT74rKOmT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3z85D1WtJIT9GvOC-DeYwS-DtQCAxK5/view?usp=sharing

here is google console error 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMvifyjGILqAjJzdWdc90jyymvdUFV5A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where does the value for `$tenantId = $result['id'];` come from?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. Actually post a [mcve] which produce the additional `</div>` output. Your method might be okay, but maybe the code around it isn't.

Comment: @NigelRen I've added the query that how I got the tenantId.